# How to pass certain attributes from resources that were created with for_each loop to other resources in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have been trying to figure out what would be the most ideal option to deploy some fundamental, mostly identical resources (vnet, subnet, bastion host, nsg, etc.) resources in Azure, using Terraform.

I have tried it with for_each and it was working just fine until I have faced a problem where I had to pass a value to an attribute from a resource which was created with for_each. Let me show you:

So this is obviously working, nothing wrong with the following resources:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "AzureBastionSubnet" {
  for_each             = var.bastion_subnet
  name                 = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.key].name
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "bastion_public_ip" {
  for_each            = toset(var.public_ip_location)
  name                = "bastion-public-ip-${each.value}"
  location            = each.value
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"

  depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.AzureBastionSubnet]
}
```

But the problem starts now when in the following resource I need to pass attribute values from resources which were created with for_each. How on earth do I pass the right attributes from the created bastion subnets and public IPs to the **subnet_id** and **public_ip_address_id**?

```
resource "azurerm_bastion_host" "bastion" {
  for_each            = toset(var.location_list)
  name                = "bastion-${each.value}"
  location            = each.value
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                 = "configuration"
    subnet_id            = azurerm_subnet.AzureBastionSubnet.id
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.bastion_public_ip.id
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_public_ip.bastion_public_ip]
}
```

Thanks!

I was looking into Terraform's **lookup**, and also the **for loop** and I am sure they could make it work but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You might be creating multiple items of `azurerm_subnet.AzureBastionSubnet` as you are using `for_each` here

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "AzureBastionSubnet" {
  for_each             = var.bastion_subnet
  name                 = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.key].name
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}
```

So you may want to refer to your individual `azurerm_subnet` instance by passing your `var.bastion_subnet` set member, or its map key.

for example:

```
resource "azurerm_bastion_host" "bastion" {
  ..

  ip_configuration {
    ...
    subnet_id            = azurerm_subnet.AzureBastionSubnet["subnet-1"].id
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_public_ip.bastion_public_ip]
}
```

Where `subnet-1` is a key in my `var.bastion_subnet` map.

---

From [Terraform documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances):

> #### Referring to Instances
>
> When `for_each` is set, Terraform distinguishes between the block
> itself and the multiple resource or module instances associated with
> it. Instances are identified by a map key (or set member) from the
> value provided to for_each.
>
> `<TYPE>.<NAME>` or `module.<NAME>` (for example,
> `azurerm_resource_group.rg`) refers to the block. `<TYPE>.<NAME>[<KEY>]`
> or `module.<NAME>[<KEY>]` (for example,
> `azurerm_resource_group.rg["a_group"]`,
> `azurerm_resource_group.rg["another_group"]`, etc.) refers to individual
> instances.